# How can I send the Windows Form element to behind in wpf application?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Hy!

I create a **WPF application**. I have a Windows Form element. This control displays the WebCamera picture.
I put it in canvas, 'cause I have to show the recodring time, so I also put a textblock into the **canvas**. My problem is that, I've already done everything with the From control, for example I set the ZIndex etc., send back, but the WebCam image always the highest lay. **I cant send it behind.** This element is a **System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost**

Can anybody **help me**? *I hope I could write my problem understandable.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not possible. `WindowsFormHost` is `HwndHost`, and according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms742522.aspx)

> HwndHost will appear on top of other WPF elements in the same
>   top-level window. However, a ToolTip or ContextMenu generated menu is
>   a separate top-level window, and so will behave correctly with
>   HwndHost.

Consider following options:

- adding overlay controls to WinForms control
- placing your overlay WPF controls inside a Popup window (you'll have to handle that window location manually)
- look for a WPF control alternative for your WinForms control (or implement your own)

Comment: Thank you max. I use a assembly what isn't mine. The webcam image is in a System.Windows.Forms.Panel, and the logic is behind it. So somehow I have to convert. What do u advise for me?

Comment: If it's a 3rd-paryt library, than there is no straightforward way to re-implement it as a WPF control. Create your own WinForms control, which hosts WebCam control and all overlay controls in it and embed this control in your WPF app - this should be the easiest way.